# jQuery UI weirdness

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, addclass, removeclass, jsfiddle

I'm very new to jQuery but keen to learn. Because of this I'm using jsFiddle to have a play and see what can be done - nothing serious, just playing with animation, etc.. specifically, the ability to animate between two classes.

Getting to the point, can you have a look at this and let me know why I need the .delay for it to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ps4Xn/2/

```
$('div').click(function() {    
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).delay(1).removeClass('clicked', 5000, 'easeInElastic');
    } else {
        $(this).delay(1).addClass('clicked', 5000, 'easeInElastic');
    }
});
```

So far as I can tell, I should be able to get rid of the two .delays, but when I do, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify things.

[Non-animated version (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Ja7hj/2/):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

[Correctly animated version (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/N4GRQ/)
[Correctly animated version (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/uzite5/3)

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked', 5000, 'easeInElastic');
});
```

The code works on jsbin but not jsfiddle - there's just something wonky with jsfiddle. It's not your code.
I generally avoid jsfiddle for tooling around with jQueryUI, since they don't play very nicely together.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was wondering if there might be a toggle for this - although, as you say, it seems that jsFiddle is being funny, as my code without the .delay works just fine on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/oheze4/edit - which is a shame, because I prefer jsfiddle over that of jsbin